# image uploading is not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

when I click button then it will return error "You did not select a file to upload." and My image is not uploaded!
now please help me what can I do?

my view is

```
<form action="insertform" enctype="multipart" name="form" method="post" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="name">Image Upload:</label>
        <div class="controls">
              <input type="file" class="input-large" name="image" id="image">
        </div>
 <form>
```

my controller is:

```
public function upload()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH."upload";
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('xyz', $error);
    } else {

        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('xyz', $data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the file input name should be "userfile", not "image".

Answer (score 0):

CI file upload file control default name is `userfile`.

If you want to change the it's name to customized one, then you have to pass the new name to upload function like :

```
  if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload("image")) // image is your new name for file control
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

either change the do_upload function call to:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
```

OR

change the input name to this:

```
<input type="file" class="input-large" name="userfile" id="image">
```

Secondly,

change your form enctype to:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```